# dijit/form/form issues POST issues in firefox

Tags: forms, dojo, submit

I am trying to post a form using `dojo.xhrPost`. Below code works fine in chrome but does not work at all in Firefox. When I say it doesn't work I see that page reloads again and nothing happens. I tried to use `dojo.stopEvent(event);` but doesn't seem to work in Firefox.

Can you please suggest me what could be my mistake. I feel the issue is more with the form than with xhrPost.

HTML Looks like below:

```html
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" data-dojo-id="myform" id="loginform" 
encType="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
<script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onSubmit">
    if(this.validate()){
        senddata();  //calling the javascript function
    }else{
        alert('Form contains invalid data.  Please correct first');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
 </script>
  <table cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
  <td><label for="name">Username:</label></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="username" name="username" 
  required="true" placeholder="Your UserName" data-dojo-
  type="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label for="password">Password:</label></td>
  <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password"       
  required="true" placeholder="Your Password" 
  data-dojotype="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"/></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <div id="response" style="float: right"></div>
 <button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" type="submit" name="submitButton" 
    value="Submit" style="float: right;">Submit</button>
 </div>
```

My Javascript code is below:

```javascript
function senddata(){
dojo.stopEvent(event);

obj = {};
obj.user_name =dijit.byId("username").get("value");
obj.password =dijit.byId("password").get("value");

var xhrArgs = {
          url: "./script/php/validatelogin.php",
          postData: obj,
          handleAs: "json",
          load: function(data){
              //alert('success');
              if(data.success==true){
                  window.location = data.message;
                  dojo.byId("response").innerHTML = "Form posted.";  
              }else{
                  dojo.byId("response").innerHTML = "login Failed";
              }

          },
          error: function(error){
             console.log("error occured!!!");
             dojo.byId("response").innerHTML = "Failed to Post the Form..";
                }
          };


//alert('starting');
 var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
 //alert('done');

 return false;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work'? What exactly does FireBug console, network traffic shows?

Answer (score 0):

First, change the `data-dojo-type` into path format. E.g.: `dijit/form/ValidationTextBox`

Second, fix your typing mistake in password field of `data-dojo-type`. You entered `data-dojotype`, missing the `-` b=in between 'dojo' & 'type'

More [information](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/byId.html) about dojo.byId() & dijit.byId().

Here is the result:

```html
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" data-dojo-id="myform" id="loginform" encType="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onSubmit">
        if(this.validate()){
            senddata();  //calling the javascript function
        }else{
            alert('Form contains invalid data.  Please correct first');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    </script>

    <table cellspacing="10">
        <tr>
            <td><label for="name">Username:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="username" name="username" required="true" placeholder="Your UserName" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="password">Password:</label></td>
            <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" required="true" placeholder="Your Password" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="response" style="float: right"></div>
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit" style="float: right;">Submit</button>
</div>

<script>
function senddata(){
    dojo.stopEvent(event);

    obj = {};
    obj.user_name =dijit.byId("username").get("value");
    obj.password =dijit.byId("password").get("value");

    var xhrArgs = {
        url: "./script/php/validatelogin.php",
        postData: obj,
        handleAs: "json",
        load: function(data){
            //alert('success');
            if(data.success==true){
                window.location = data.message;
                dojo.byId("response").innerHTML = "Form posted.";  
            }else{
                dojo.byId("response").innerHTML = "login Failed";
            }
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log("error occured!!!");
            dojo.byId("response").innerHTML = "Failed to Post the Form..";
        }
    };
    //alert('starting');
    var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
    //alert('done');
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I had it right way originally but it did not work so I constantly changed lots of things. Anyway I made the suggested changes but it does not work. Is this could be a Firefox issue? It works fine in chrome though.

Comment: I suggest you slim you code, as you said your code is work in Chrome, means basically not the code problem. If the problem still occur, please let me know your platform detail, such as FF version, dojo version. I will help you to have a test if I am free.

Comment: I just faced firefox issues with dijit/form/Form when and only when using a native "<form>" tag. I changed it to a regular div and my issue went away... not sure if this is the same problem, but I thought that could help...